# Capture line only if there is no numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically I am trying to write a regex in Javascript that looks for a certain string, but I don't want it to match if that string contains a number. It is hard to explain so an exmaple will be better.

String:
Blah blah blah
Blah 233 blah
Match: Blah blah blah
Don't Match: Blah 233 blah

I have tried negative lookaheads, and other means to get it to work but it is beyond me on how I would get it to work as I am very inexperienced with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match each line using this expression:

```
var re = /^\D*$/mg,
line;

while ((line = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(line);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/yodemape/1/)

The expression matches one line whereby all characters are not digits; the `/m` modifier makes `^` and `$` match the start and ending of each line respectively (as opposed to the entire subject).

Answer (score 0):

simply enough:

```
js> s = "ao123eu";
"ao123eu"
js> if (s.match(/\d/) === null) { print("has no number"); } else { print("has number") }
has number

js> s = "aoeu";
"aoeu"
js> if (s.match(/\d/) === null) { print("has no number"); } else { print("has number") }
has no number
```

all I'm doing, is matching against `\d` any number appearing exactly once in the string.

And you can make it a function:

```
function has_number(s) {
    return s.match(/\d/) !== null;
}
```

which returns true if there's a number in the string.

Now if you want to do a replace, you can do:

```
function remove_numbers(s) {
    return s.replace(/\d+/g, "\\_o<")
}
```

which gives:

```
js> print(remove_numbers("ao234u 42 ao1234eu"))
ao\_o<u \_o< ao\_o<eu
```

Comment: I plan to use this with a string replace that will have many possible matches, I don't think this will be appropriate.

Comment: Minor point: you don't even need the `+` if *any* digit needs to invalidate the match.

Comment: well, I'm answering to your question, and what I gave you works! Please make another question if my answer does not match what you need!

Comment: and I've added another function that replaces every number into ascii art ducks. Hope you'll like it! ;-)